# How do I convert 24 hours format to time hh:mm:tt in SSRS?

Tags: time

How do I convert 24 hours format into time format in SSRS? So for example e.g. (120 become 1:20 AM or 1420 become 2:20 PM)

Comment: Thanks but in the field there is 50 also that mean 12:50 AM how we can do in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your integer field into an SSRS datetime and then set the display to represent "H:MM tt" like you want.

1. Parse into date/time with an expression like

   =CDate("2/28/2017 " + LEFT("0230",2) + ":" + RIGHT("0230",2))

Note that I picked a random date and appended "0230" representing the time to it.  In your case, replace "0230" with "Fields!YourFieldName.Value" where YourFieldName is the column in your dataset.

2. Right click on your expression, go to "Text Box Properties", "Number" pane, and set your expression format in the "time" menu.